# Power BI Dax: How to create relative date slicer by using Switch in Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to create a dax formula in a measure that will filter records by relative dates. However, It didn't return the desired result. Please see below DAX formula for reference:

```
RelativePeriod = 
VAR SelectedPeriod =
    SELECTEDVALUE (Period[Period])
VAR DynamicPeriod =
    SWITCH (
        TRUE(),
        SelectedPeriod = "Yesterday", today()-1,
        SelectedPeriod = "MTD", DATESMTD('Date'[CalendarDate]),
        SelectedPeriod = "QTD", DATESQTD('Date'[CalendarDate]),
        SelectedPeriod = "YTD", DATESYTD('Date'[CalendarDate]),
        SelectedPeriod = "Last Year", PREVIOUSYEAR('Date'[CalendarDate]),
        BLANK()
    )
RETURN
    DynamicPeriod
```

Date Table to test if the relative filter works:
[image]

Period table:

[image]

RelativePeriod Measure:

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to build a calculated table that would respond to user selections? It's not possible.

Comment: Hi @RADO Nope. The table above is only a test table to see if my relative filter works. However, it didn't work with above dax formula

Comment: I am not talking about the table in your visuals. I am talking about the table calculated by your DAX formula.

Comment: @RADO Edited my question above by including the period table I mentioned in DAX. Hope it makes sense

Comment: You are missing my point. You created RelativePeriod as a calculated table, correct?

Comment: Nope. It is a measure not a calculated table

Comment: That's not true, it can not be a measure. DynamicPeriod returns a table, because most time intelligence functions you used return tables. Measures can not return tables, only single values.

Comment: @RADO edited my question above to include the RelativePeriod measure in my Date table